# How to get 'domain\userid' in SAML response for Name ID, ADFS3.0

Tags: saml, spring-saml, adfs3.0

My application uses SAML spring security and SSO is established with ADFS 3.0
I am getting only username in SAML response for NameID. 
for e.g.

```
<NameID>user</NameID>.
```

I want response in format of 'domain\UserID' to work functionality of application properly. Current claim rule is set as:

1. Claim rule Template: 'Send LDAP attribute as claims'
2. Attribute Store: Active Directory
3. LDAP Attribute: Sam-account-Name
4. Outgoing Name Type: Name ID

So what changes required in Claims Rule to get Name ID as 'domain\username' format

Answer (score 0):

From memory, WindowsAccountName is in this form.

So just a Transform rule from this to NameID.